# Why: No such module 'SCRecorder' when using Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I have included screenshots of all the relevant information. Project: https://github.com/alex-paterson/SCRecorder-swift-example

please answer as if I'm a newb. Thank you

[image: See photo]

Comment: Have you add `#import <SCRecorder/SCRecorder.h>` in your bridge header?

Comment: after `pod install` or `pod update`, you must reopen the `*.xcworkspace` instead of the `.xcodeproj` with Xcode in your project folder, check this.

Comment: @ezatu丶tx worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after `pod install` or `pod update`, you must reopen the `*.xcworkspace` instead of the `.xcodeproj` with Xcode in your project folder, check this.